# Python customize behavior by passing a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a function that takes 2 regular parameters (string), and 1 function. The main functionality is to work with the 2 string parameters (e.g. save to database). The function parameter will allow for extra behavior to be added. Example:

```
def call(arg1, arg2, func):
    save(arg1, arg2) # main functionality here.
    if callable(func):
        func(arg1, arg2)

def with_callback():
    def log(*args):
        values = ', '.join(str(x) for x in args)
        print('call used with arguments: {values}'.format(values=values)

    call('example', 'case', log)
```

The idea is the same as **Effective Python**:

> [Item 23](http://www.effectivepython.com/2015/02/12/accept-functions-for-simple-interfaces-instead-of-classes/): Accept Functions for Simple Interfaces Instead of Classes.

The implementation would thus be similar to `list.sort(key=somefunc)` or the first parameter of `collections.defaultdict`.

So the question boils down to:

**How do I implement a function (or class?) to take a function as parameter so that custom behavior can be defined?**

(or phrased differently: *What is the preferred way to customize behavior when using functions as parameters?*)

Comment: You pass in a function object? I'm not sure I get what your asking.

Comment: @leaf The Effective Python link should explain it better than I can, but yes. The function has some main-functionality (arg1, arg2) and it allows you to customize some behavior by sending in another function.

Comment: What's not clear to me is what's not clear about the example code. It should work fine, and I don't know what you need to know that it doesn't cover.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I was wondering if there was a better way to handle this (more pythonic?). Perhaps decorators could take care of this, or perhaps there is some other way that I don't know of yet (only used python for about 3 weeks, coming from Java).

Comment: you've missed parentheses after formatting your string.. Btw, are you trying to implement a decorator with a func as a parameter?

Comment: @pivanchy I'm trying to accomplish the same as was written at item 23 of effective python. If a decorator can/should be used for that, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way to do this is to a default argument of `None`:

```
def call(arg1, arg2, func=None):
  save(arg1, arg2)
  if func is not None:
    func(arg1, arg2)
```